# Simple WPF validation not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

Sorry if this is a silly question, but i'm having trouble to implement validation on my viewmodel class. My code looks like this:

```
class modClienteViewModel : Screen, IHandle<vw_ClientesFull>, IDataErrorInfo
{
public Clientes Cliente { get; set; }                

public modClienteViewModel(int IDCliente)
{
  Cliente = serviceClient.Cliente_GetById(IDCliente);
}

public string Error
    {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get {
            string sError = "";
            if (columnName == "Cliente")
                sError = "Validation of Client";
            return sError;
        }
    }
}
```

The object "Cliente" is load from WCF Service. So in my contructor I load the client INFO, and showit on WPF control using bindings to properties of Cliente object.
The i'm facing is that the method for validation never fired from object Cliente, so i cannot analize its propertis to validate. I don't know if i'm beeing clear enough but this line:

```
sError = "Validation of Client";
```

never get executed because columname never get value "Cliente".I'm sure i'm doing something wrong here, please help! Thanks!                    sError = "Validation of Client";

Comment: You have to turn it on in the binding.  `{Binding Derp, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}`  You doing that?

Comment: @Will i'm using Caliburn.micro so binding is a little different. Anyway i try this: <TextBox x:Name="Cliente_RazonSocial" Text="{Binding Cliente.RazonSocial,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/> with no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if validation will work at the `Cliente` level. Instead I think you need to have the `Cliente` class implement IDataErrorInfo, where you should perform validation on the individual properties (e.g. `RazonSocial`) that have been bound to UI controls.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your idea. I try that, but the problem with this approach is that the class Cliente is defined on server-side y pass over WCF. I don't think validation can pass through WCF channel (need to be serialized).

Comment: The possible solution which I can think of is to `Wrap` the original `Client` response into a new class which implements `IDataErrorInfo` and then bind using this class to your `View`

Comment: Thank asks81, i try that. I create a class that inherits Client and implement IDataErrorInfo. The problem is that c# won't let me transform or asign this derivated class with the original class data. I would need to copy all properties by hand (and there is a lot of properties)